# Mapping Array of CustomTypes Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I am facing the following issue. In a PostgreSQL database, I created some composite types like the following:

```sql
CREATE TYPE public.direct_modification AS (
  "columnName"  text,
  "newValue"    text,
  "oldValue"    text
);
```

Then I use this type as the columns type:

```sql
ADD COLUMN "modificationText" public._direct_modification[] NOT NULL;
```

I am using HIbernate to map the database. By default, Hibernate mapped all unknown types using the Serialization. I want to create some java Classes, like for example DirectModification, which contain the separate types of the composite type on the java side.

How do I map those types using mapping files(hbm.xml)? I have read, that I should create a class, that implements CompositeUserType. But how I let the Hibernate put it all into an Array?